# what's wrong with array of structures?

Tags: c++, structure

I want to input the vertices of a triangle and find the area of the triangle. I read the vertices and tried to print it. But it's showing error. Can you help me out.I tried the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
struct vertex {
    float x;
    float y;
};

struct triangle {
    vertex vertices[3];
};

int main()
{
    triangle t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        double x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        vertex p = { x, y };
        cout << p;
        t.vertices[i] = p;
        // cout<<t.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the error as well?

Comment: error is in cout <<p line.wat's wrong with it

Comment: No; show the error. What does it say?

Comment: note:   cannot convert ���p��� (type ���vertex���) to type ���const unsigned char*���
     cout<<p;
           ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& oss, const vertex& v) {
    return oss << '(' << v.x << ',' << v.y << ')';
}
```

It is most likely complaining because it doesn't know how to display the struct you are trying to print.

---

Even though you stored it as `{x, y}`, the result is that `p` is still an object. C++ just gives you that ability to create objects using the [**list initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) syntax. To actually display this object is a different issue altogether because all it sees is some object for which the `<<` operator is not defined to handle, so it throws it's virtual hands up in the air and spit out an error message.

But because we have just created a definition of that operator which handles the said object that was proving difficult, it now knows what to do when it sees a vertex object.

Hope that helps

Comment: i didnt understand the code.i'm a beginner.cout<<v.x<<v.y is enough?i just want to print as (x,y)

Comment: @user3217708, fair enough, I just thought since you were using `cout << p` I might as well give an answer that doesn't prevent that

Comment: vertex p = {x, y};
      //cout<<p;     why this is not working ? p is the vertex with x and y co-ordinate and it is stored as {x,y}

Comment: @user3217708, see my added explanation